# what should I do if I want to see the tablview from the last

Tags: iphone, uitableview

hey I want to make a demo of chat.so when I open UITableView for it, it should display from the last and previous item should be in upper side.. i.e., I want to scroll my UITableView to the last row automatically when user opens the chat screen. what should i do?

my code is-

```
cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}

    [lblName setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:12]];
    lblName.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    lblName.numberOfLines = 0;
    lblName.text=[arrUsername objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    lblName.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [lblName setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
    if ([[arrCommentUid objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
        [lblName setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft];
    }
    else
```

please help!! its the code for just optional.cell of UITableView

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this for chat application

[SSMessagesviewcontroller](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ssmessagesviewcontroller)
[stbubbletableviewcell](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stbubbletableviewcell)
[bubblethingie](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/bubblethingie)
[uibubbletableview](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/uibubbletableview)
[styledchat](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/styledchat)
[acanichat](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/acanichat)

and also you can go to last row using

```
   [tableView reloadData];
   int lastRowNumber = [tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1;
   NSIndexPath* ip = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowNumber inSection:0];
   [tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:ip atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you should sort your array in descending order.Thus it will display your data from last to first.

For that you can use NSSortDescriptor

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:nil ascending:NO selector:@selector(localizedCompare:)];
NSArray* sortedArray = [<YOURS_ARRAY> sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor]];
```

Enjoy Programming !

Answer (score -1):

You can scroll to last using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath`

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

And you can get indexPath of last row using

`NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([yourTableAry count] - 1) inSection:0`];

Or

`NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1) inSection:0`];

**EDIT**

If you want to goto top of row then

```
NSIndexPath *firstRowIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];

[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:firstRowIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Comment: where i write this code?

Comment: but after usinf this code i cant go upside..what i do?

Comment: you can scroll upside dear.. or you can get lower indexPath and use this code again

Comment: can you give me code? please. i am new in iOS

Comment: check my answer again to go to top buddy

Comment: i want both downside in starting and can check also upside as need..What will be the condition i write?

Comment: sir basically problem is that at first time it will go to downside perfectly but i m not going to upper side..what should i do?

Comment: how you want to go upside? any button click?

Comment: so just scroll up your tableview

Comment: it not work scroll,is any code to scroll?

Comment: where are you putting scrollToRowAtIndexPath ?

Comment: in mid of cellforrowat inderpath

Comment: put this line where you are getting your new message.., because whenever you scroll your table , your cellforrow will call, and it will again redirect you to bottom

Comment: but i want in starting it will goes to the down(last to up)

Comment: ok make one condition in your cellforrow, that indexPath.row==[yourAry count] then put scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath

Comment: ok thanks Rajneesh for the help.

Comment: your welcome.. @user2522863(make your own name :))

Comment: hey Rajneesh ..its not work.

Comment: `if (indexPath.row==[arrcomment count]) {
       NSIndexPath *lastIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:([tblview numberOfRowsInSection:0] - 1) inSection:0];
        [tblview scrollToRowAtIndexPath:lastIndexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
    }
`

Comment: sry rajneesh..its work perfectly..u r rock buddy:)

Comment: thanks @Jeet :) you can accept answer and upvote it too